# How to decrypt hash security in phalcon

Tags: phalcon

Save crypt hash security:

```
$usuario = new User();
$usuario->password = $this->security->hash($this->request->getPost("pass"));
if (!$usuario->save()) {
    foreach ($usuario->getMessages() as $message) {
    $this->flash->error($message);
    }
    $this->dispatcher->forward([
        'controller' => "usuario",
        'action' => 'new'
    ]);
    return;
}
```

now, How to decrypt hash security to send my form:

```
$usuario = User::findFirstByid($iduser);
$this->tag->setDefault("pass", $this->encryption->decrypt($usuario->password));
```

I having this: Notice: Access to undefined property encryption in ...

Comment: You can't decrypt hashes. By definition hash is only one-way. Also there i no such service as encryption in phalcon.

Answer (score 0):

As @Juri said Hashes are only one way. You can however use `encryptBase64()` which is two way and you can decode it back. **Do not use it for passwords, use it for some data you need to pass to someone and read it back, like api token etc..**

Here is how to set it up:

```
$di->setShared('crypt', function () use ($config) {
    $crypt = new \Phalcon\Crypt();
    $crypt->setKey('i$4^&/:%2@k50ROQ<@{(e=*!<7u|rI~0');
    return $crypt;
});
```

Helper functions I created, but you can use it directly:

```
...
...

private static $cryptKey = 'i$4^&/:%2@k50ROQ<@{(e=*!<7u|rI~0';

/**
 *  Generate url safe encoded string
 *
 *  @param string $string string to be encoded
 *  @return encoded string
 */
public static function encodeString($string)
{
    $crypt = new \Phalcon\Crypt();
    return $crypt->encryptBase64($string, self::$cryptKey, true);
}

/**
 *  Decode string generated with Common::encodeString()
 *
 *  @param string $string Encoded string
 *  @return decoded string
 */
public static function decodeString($string)
{
    $crypt = new \Phalcon\Crypt();
    return $crypt->decryptBase64($string, self::$cryptKey, true);
}
```